# Synchronizing http GET and POST request

Tags: serial, esp8266

My project aims to send `HTTP GET` request to web page(using Arduino UNO and ESP8266-01) then receive response, extract wanted values from response and react with(for example turn on LED1,LED3) then resend led's status to another web page to be inserted in mysql database using `HTTP POST` in order to make sure that Arduino received the command and executed successfully (in an infinitive loop).
Each request `HTTP GET` or `HTTP POST` works fine alone, but when trying to do that in a sequence `HTTP GET` then `HTTP POST` inside the loop I got bad result shown in serial monitor like unknown strange characters.
Here is my `loop` :

```
void loop() {
  if (millis() - lastTimeMillis > 40000) {
    lastTimeMillis = millis();
    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
    delay(1000);
    printResponse();
    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=4,\"TCP\",\"" + server + "\",80");
    delay(1000);
    printResponse();
    String cmd = "GET /ard/sensor.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost";
    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=4," + String(cmd.length() + 4));
    delay(1000);
    ESP8266.println(cmd);
    delay(1000);
    ESP8266.println("");    
  }
    if (ESP8266.available()){
    Serial.write(ESP8266.read());
    }
  Value1=(digitalRead (LED_PIN1));
  Value2=(digitalRead (LED_PIN2));
  Value3=(digitalRead (LED_PIN3));
  Value4=(digitalRead (LED_PIN4)); 
 data = "Value1=" + Value1 + "&Value2=" + Value2 + "&Value3=" + Value3  + "&Value4=" + Value4;
  httppost();
}
```

And here is

> httppost()

```
void httppost () {

    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"" + server + "\",80");
    if( ESP8266.find("OK")) {
    Serial.println("TCP connection ready");
    }
    String postRequest =
    "POST " + uri + " HTTP/1.0\r\n" +
    "Host: " + server + "\r\n" +
    "Accept: *" + "/" + "*\r\n" +
    "Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" +
    "\r\n" + data;
    String sendCmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
    ESP8266.print(sendCmd);
    ESP8266.println(postRequest.length() );
    delay(5000);
    if(ESP8266.find(">")) { Serial.println("Sending.."); ESP8266.print(postRequest);    
    if( ESP8266.find("SEND OK")) { Serial.println("Packet sent");    
    while (ESP8266.available()) {    
    String tmpResp = ESP8266.readString();    
    Serial.println(tmpResp);    
    }    
    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
    }
    }
}
```

When uploading this code it seems like only `HTTP POST` works fine in a loop while `HTTP GET` having a trouble. So how to make them both work fine in a loop?
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you like AT commands? I do not. Use a library https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp or program the esp8266 with esp8266 Arduino core package https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#installing-with-boards-manager

Comment: Why does one use `AT+CIPSEND=4,<N>` and the other `AT+CIPSEND=<N>`?

Comment: @Gerben This is the first time I deal with Arduino, may you explain more please ?

Comment: Try removing the `4,`, or try adding it to both.